# MySQL : Calculate last 12 month data

Tags: mysql

I am trying to get the sum of value for last 12 month excluding this month.

Below is the sample data.

[image]

I tried using this query but it is not returning any record.

Here is the query which I have created.

```
SELECT id, sum(amount) FROM mydatatable where YEAR(datetime) = YEAR(CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 12 MONTH) AND MONTH(datetime) = MONTH(CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 12 MONTH)
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: *get the sum of value for last 12 month excluding this month* Do you need to start from 1st of month a year ago and finish at 1st of current month? I.e. today (2021-06-17) you need to aggregate data from 2020-06-01 inclusive till 2021-06-01 exclusive, is it?

Comment: No. I want to calculate it this way. Just an example current month is June. So I want the calculation from may 2020 to may 2021.

Comment: *from may 2020 to may 2021.* Both - inclusive? from 2020-05-10 till 2021-02-31? this is 13 months..

Comment: Not actually I was giving example. So if want to calculate 12 months data excluding current month then we can go backwards for 12 months and date should start with 1st and end with 30 or 31.

Comment: Show definite dates literals (like me), do not describe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Just an example current month is June. So I want the calculation from may 2020 to may 2021. – Rocx

If this means "from 2020-05-01 inclusive till 2021-05-01 exclusive" then

```sql
SELECT id, SUM(amount) 
FROM mydatatable 
WHERE `datetime` >= DATE_FORMAT(CURRENT_DATE, '%Y-%m-01') - INTERVAL '1 1' YEAR_MONTH
  AND `datetime` < DATE_FORMAT(CURRENT_DATE, '%Y-%m-01') - INTERVAL 1 MONTH
```

If this means something else then simply adjust substracted intervals. For example, for "from 2020-06-01 inclusive till 2021-06-01 exclusive" this will be

```sql
SELECT id, SUM(amount) 
FROM mydatatable 
WHERE `datetime` >= DATE_FORMAT(CURRENT_DATE, '%Y-%m-01') - INTERVAL 1 YEAR
  AND `datetime` < DATE_FORMAT(CURRENT_DATE, '%Y-%m-01')
```

Comment: `datetime` >= DATE_FORMAT(CURRENT_DATE, '%Y-%m-01') - INTERVAL '1 1' YEAR_MONTH
  AND `datetime` < DATE_FORMAT(CURRENT_DATE, '%Y-%m-01') - INTERVAL 1 MONTH - i am getting error seems like keywords are not correct. Year_Month

Comment: @Rocx https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/expressions.html#temporal-intervals claims that YEAR_MONTH is correct, and I agree with it because I use this in practice. Ensure: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&rdbms2=mysql_5.5&fiddle=829de6e2c6e11de9b6af9b7fc32d8bbb If you get an error then you did something wrongly... provide complete and unchanged error message.

Comment: I checked that but for some reason it is not recognising it in phpmyadmin. When i run it i can see errors.

Comment: @Rocx This is phpmyadmin problem - it is either too old or too stupid. Replace it with more correct client. As  palliative use `DATE_FORMAT(CURRENT_DATE, '%Y-%m-01') - INTERVAL 1 YEAR - INTERVAL 1 MONTH`.

Comment: I think i found the issue. I have added the brackets and it worked. `datetime` >= (DATE_FORMAT(CURRENT_DATE, '%Y-%m-01') - INTERVAL '1 1' YEAR_MONTH) AND `datetime` < DATE_FORMAT(CURRENT_DATE, '%Y-%m-01') - INTERVAL 1 MONTH

Answer (score -1):

SELECT id, sum(amount) FROM mydatatable where datetime > now() - INTERVAL 11 month;

Comment: This will include this month data too.